# How to separate variables from other text in bash

Tags: bash

Is this the way to separate variables from other text in bash:

```
${PROJECT}_${GITCOMMIT}.tar.gz
```

if PROJECT = test
AND GITCOMMIT = 222

Will this give you test_222.tar.gz?
When should you use braces {} when it comes to variables?
Are there other ways to separate the variables in bash from text?

Comment: No, it will give you `test_222.tar.gz`

Comment: Are you asking how bash does it? Are you asking how to implement it yourself programatically? What exactly is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the way to do it. Your question is garbled however; you've got an underscore between the two variable expressions, so you won't get "test" and "222" adjacent to eachother in the resulting string.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the braces are how you delimit text in the variable name from following text. In you case,

```
$PROJECT$GITCOMMIT.tar.gz  # test222.tar.gz
```

would be sufficient, because the `$` that starts `GITCOMMIT` can't be part of the preceding parameter name. (Same for the `.` just before `tar`; there can't be a variable named `GITCOMMIT.`.) If `$PROJECT` were followed by *literal* text, the braces would be necessary:

```
$PROJECT_$GITCOMMIT.tar.gz  # WRONG: No variable PROJECT_
${PROJECT}_$GITCOMMIT.tar.gz # CORRECT: test_222.tar.gz
```